# Should a CAN Bus-Off condition immediately reset the connection flags despite of Nodeguarding?

Tags: connection, can-bus, canopen

I am wondering whether a detected CAN Bus-Off condition should have a direct impact on the connection status flags in my CANopen Master. It is connected to CAN Nodes that handle analog and digital I/O.

For each Node there is a flag in the CANopen Master stating its connection status to that CAN node (TRUE/FALSE), it is controlled by the Nodeguarding response handler.
Whenever our Nodeguarding RTR frame gets responded by the Node, it is set to TRUE, otherwise, after reaching the Life Time with no answer, it is set to FALSE. The default Life Time is 3x 500 ms = 1,5 seconds.

So, when I detect a Bus-Off condition before the Life Time of that Node expires: Should I immediately reset the connection status flag to FALSE, or should I just wait and see for the Nodeguarding to expire?

I think it could well happen that the Bus-Off condition goes away before the Nodeguarding would expire, and I don't know if it is a good idea to be that intolerant.

Comment: I believe either should result in a state transition to NMT stop, but I'd have to check the standard to tell for sure.